# Class validator for nested object or object ID

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I want to create a user with organisationId passed and if the organisation is not available, I want the organisation object to be passed too.

```
export class User {
  @IsString()
  public name: string;

  @IsNumber()
  public organisationId: number;
}

export class Organisation {
  @IsString()
  public name: string;
}
```

So basically, if the request is

```
{
  name: "user name",
  organisationId: 1
}
```

I will create the user as organisation(with id 1) is already present.
For the request

```
{
  name: "user name",
  organisation: {
    name: "org name"
  }
}
```

I will be creating the organisation and the user. And in this case, want the validator to work on organisation too. Here I need either organisationId or organisation. How to achieve this? Is there a way to make sure only one is available?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the ValidateIf decorator and solve my issue. Thanks.

```
export class User {
  @IsString()
  public name: string;

  @IsNumber()
  @ValidateIf(o => !o.organisation)
  public organisationId: number;

  @ValidateIf(o => !o.organisationId)
  public organisation: Organisation;
}
```